# Struts2 submit button with id in iterated list

Tags: struts2

How do I use a struts submit button to submit the specific id of an object in an iterated list?

```xml
<s:form action="actionDeleteBooking">
    <s:iterator var = "bookingList" value="bookings">
        <s:submit label="delete booking" value = "cancel booking" theme = "simple" id="bookingid"  />
    </s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

I can do if for a radio button:

```xml
<s:form action="actionConfirmBooking">
    <s:iterator var = "pathList" value="results">
        <s:iterator var = "flightList" value="pathList">
            <s:radio name="flightSelected" list="flightList" listKey = "flightid"   id = "flightid" value = "flightid"/>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
    <s:submit label="Submit" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*if* what you are trying to achieve is to have a submit button for each "row", submitting one value, then use multiple forms and an hidden field:

```xml
<s:iterator var = "bookingList" value="bookings">
    <s:form action="actionDeleteBooking">
        <s:hidden name="selectedItem" value="%{bookingid}" />
        <s:submit label="delete booking" value="cancel booking" theme="simple" />
    </s:form>
</s:iterator>
```

Otherwise use an `<s:a />`, or set a field with JavaScript, or describe better what you want.

Comment: this is setting the selectedItem field to "bookingid" instead of the id.when i print it out it gets it fine: `<s:property  value="bookingid" />`

Comment: the syntax i needed was `<s:hidden name="selectedBookingId" value="%{bookingid}"id = "bookingid" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `checkbox` tag for the items you want to delete. You should be able to do this because you have already used similar form with `s:radio`.

```jsp
<s:form action="actionDeleteBooking">
   <s:iterator var = "bookingList" value="bookings">
       <s:checkbox name="bookingids" label="bookingid" />
   </s:iterator>
   <s:submit label="delete bookings" value = "cancel booking" theme = "simple"/>
</s:form>
```